# How to loop through a matrix in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro that will create a matrix based upon an equation in an VBA.

For example:
If I have the following 3x3 matrix:

```
3  5  7
6  3  4
1  2  3
```

I want to create a 3x3 matrix that takes the value 1st value and divides it by the sum of the row, and so on.

```
0.2  0.3  0.5
0.5  0.2  0.3
0.2  0.3  0.5
```

I tried the following code:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("C2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select 'So the new matrix starts underneath the old matrix
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
i = 4
n = 1
Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
    ActiveCell.FormulaRnC1 = "=RiC3/SUM(RiC3:RiC52)*100"
    i = i + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

The number or rows will vary.

I have limited experience with this platform, please let me know how to improve framing this question.

Comment: Will his matrix be input in a particular location in the workbook?

Comment: Input matrix starts at Row 3, Column 4. The output matrix will be 2 rows underneath underneath the original matrix on the same worksheet.

Comment: First, that is horrible design. Output the new matrix to a new workbook, or at least to the side of the originla. Second, I was asking where the original matrix will be input. It is hard to provide code without knowing the design.

Comment: Do you need a macro? Wouldn't you be able to do this with formulas instead? Also you have a typo, `.FormulaRnC1`  should be `.FormulaR1C1`, and change `"=RiC3` to just `"=RC3`, etc., no?

Comment: @Kyle A new workbook would be better, the matrix contains 124 columns.

Comment: @ BruceWayne I foresee myself doing this multiple times with other data, which is why I wanted to create the macro.

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you put your first matrix on `Sheet1` starting in cell A1. This will output the other Matrix to the new workbook, Sheet1, starting in cell A1.

```
Sub example()
Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
Dim row_sum As Double
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim wbk As Workbook

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    x = .Range("a1:" & .Cells(.Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Address).Value2
End With

y = x

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)
        row_sum = .Sum(.Index(x, i))
            For j = LBound(x, 2) To UBound(x, 2)
                y(i, j) = x(i, j) / row_sum
            Next j
    Next i
End With

Set wbk = Workbooks.Add

wbk.Sheets(1).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(y, 1), UBound(y, 2)) = y


End Sub
```

Comment: I copy pasted the matrix to a new workbook, sheet one, starting at A1 as recommended but when running the code, the following appeared: "Run-time error'13': type mismatch"

Comment: Which line of code gives you the error? Did you put the code in the workbook with the matrix?

Comment: I had it under a module in the personal.xlsb which is why it did not work. When I placed the code under the workbook with the matrix, it ran beautifully! Thank you Kyle.

Comment: Certainly, happy to help.